# Mantener mismo id de un registro de Base de datos durante una sesion

Tags: python, mysql, flask

estoy haciendo un programa de presupuestos, usando Python y Flask, además de MySQL para almacenar los datos en una BDD. El problema que tengo, es que aunque los datos me los inserta en dos tablas, relacionadas por un id, cuando se hace un nuevo registro aunque la "session" este activa, me genera un nuevo id, en lugar de mantener el que se creo desde un principio. comparto codigo de mi función que recibe los datos desde el formulario y la función que me inserta los datos en las tablas.

```
class Presupuesto:
def __init__(self):
    self.contador_partida = 1
    self.rutas()

def calcular_totales(self, importe, subtotal):
    iva = 0.08 * subtotal
    total = iva + subtotal
    mano_obra = subtotal * 0.40
    materiales = subtotal * 0.60
    return iva, total, mano_obra, materiales

def index(self):
    clientes = bd_tabla_clientes()
    subtotal = 0

    if "form_data" not in session:
        session["form_data"] = []

    if "cliente_id" not in session:
        session["cliente_id"] = None

    if request.method == "POST":
        datos = request.form.to_dict()
        datos["partida"] = int(self.contador_partida)

        fecha = datetime.now()
        datos["fecha"] = fecha.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        importe = float(datos.get("importe"))
        subtotal += importe

        iva, total, mano_obra, materiales = self.calcular_totales(importe, subtotal)

        datos["materiales"] = materiales
        datos["mano_obra"] = mano_obra
        datos["subtotal"] = subtotal
        datos["iva"] = iva
        datos["total"] = total

        session["form_data"].append(datos)
        self.sel_cliente(request.form.get("cliente_id"))
        self.contador_partida += 1

        # Llamar a la función para insertar datos en la base de datos
        presupuesto_id = insertar_datos_presupuesto(datos)
        if presupuesto_id is not None:
            print(f"Presupuesto insertado con ID: {presupuesto_id}")
        else:
            print("Error al insertar el presupuesto en la base de datos")

        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    return render_template(
        "index.html", clientes=clientes, registros=session["form_data"]
    )
```

función para insertar los datos en la BDD. aclaro que son archivos diferentes:

```
def insertar_datos_presupuesto(presupuesto):
try:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(**db_params)
    cursor = db.cursor()



    # Insertar datos en la tabla 'presupuestos'
    sql_presupuesto = "INSERT INTO presupuestos (cliente_id, fecha, materiales, mano_obra, subtotal, iva, total) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    valores_presupuesto = (
        presupuesto["cliente_id"],
        presupuesto["fecha"],
        presupuesto["materiales"],
        presupuesto["mano_obra"],
        presupuesto["subtotal"],
        presupuesto["iva"],
        presupuesto["total"],
    )
    print(valores_presupuesto)

    cursor.execute(sql_presupuesto, valores_presupuesto)
    db.commit()
    presupuesto_id = cursor.lastrowid
    print(presupuesto_id)

    # Insertar datos en la tabla 'presupuestos_partidas'
    sql_partida = "INSERT INTO presupuestos_partidas (presupuesto_id, partida, descripcion, cantidad, precio, importe, material) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    valores_partida = (
        presupuesto_id,
        presupuesto["partida"],  # Cambiado a presupuesto["partida"]
        presupuesto["descripcion"],
        presupuesto["cantidad"],
        presupuesto["precio"],
        presupuesto["importe"],
        presupuesto["material"],
    )
    print(valores_partida)

    cursor.execute(sql_partida, valores_partida)
    db.commit()


    return presupuesto_id
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    # Manejo de errores
    print(f"Error de base de datos: {err}")
    db.rollback()
    return None
finally:
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

Comment: Yo no entiendo de cual ID hablas que es el que cambia...

Comment: el "id_presupuesto". Aunque este abierta la sesión, cuando se registran datos nuevos usando el formulario, me genera un id_presupuesto nuevo, en lugar de mantener el id_presupuesto que ya se había generado.

Comment: Y porque decis que deberia mantenerlo??? en donde lo estas manteniendo??

Comment: sabes que?, tienes razón, en ninguna parte, he creado una variable de sesión que me almacene el "id_presupuesto". investigare como implementarlo. Saludos.